# Can the public see search queries made by users on a website with Google Custom Search?

Tags: data-leakage, search-engines

Can search queries that have been made by users on a website that uses Google Custom Search be viewed by people that are not staff of the website?

Comment: Are you asking if such access is possible by default? Or do you ask if a website can be misconfigured to allow such access by accident?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'd appreciate an answer to both. The website in question is pastebin, so I'm going to assume it isn't misconfigured because of it's size, but is it possible?